# In Perl, how can I start processing a file starting from a given string?

Tags: loops, csv, perl, if-statement

I need to open a very messy csv file (by messy I mean blank columns and rows in between data and I only need data from some of the columns) and only start allocating data to columns once it reaches a given line with the word 'Information A' or 'Informasie A' (the files are in one of two different languages but hold the same format). The table has a format more or less as follows:

```
(n) Name
(n) General info
(n) ID
(n) Contact
(n) General
(n)
(a) Information A
(a)
(a) Name
(a) one
(a) two
(a) three
(a)
(a) four
(a) five
(a) Total
(b) Information B
(b)
(b) Name
```

The basic outline of the program was written for me which initially worked where the first section of extra details was designated by $part='n' (shown as (n) above), while that which comes after 'Information A' was designated 'a' and so forth. However, I think I may have deleted some of the code which made the whole extraction unusable. I tried fixing it but that has seen to do more damage than good so I'm trying to do it over from scratch and hopefully learn an easier way to do it in the process.

The code that I have so far is as follows:

```
open (IN_F, "$file") or die "Can't open $file";

  my %file;

while (<IN_F>){

  my $line = $_;
     $line =~ s/\s*$//g;
     $line =~ s/\-//g;

  my $part='n';
     $part='a' if (substr($line,0,13) eq 'Information A');
     $part='b' if (substr($line,0,13) eq 'Information B');

  next if $part='a';
  last if substr($line,0,20) eq 'Litter Information B';

  print "$line\n";
}
exit;
```

where I want the print to then be:

```
Name
one
two
three
four
five
Total
```

I found similar questions that had different solutions; some of them used line number but mine aren't constant. A different solution used '..', which I tried but I think I didnt apply it correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program below will do as you ask. It is *essential* to `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, and declare your variables with `my`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $file = 'information.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

my $part = 'n';

while  ( <$fh> ) {

    if ( /(?:Information|Informasie) ([A-Z])/ ) {
        $part = $1;
        next;
    }

    print if $part eq 'A';
}
```

#### output

```
Name
one
two
three
four
five
Total
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to see if this works.. I actually do have use strict and use warning, just forgot to add it. The person that did the outline of the program for me didn't add these, and after I came across them and saw that they are very important, I added them and obviously spent a day googling and cleaning all the warnings!

Comment: On a different note.. Is there a nice webpage or reference that explains all the commands you have used? It's great knowing what to do but I would also like to learn why I am using them and what each piece does! I'm still very new to perl and programming and have lots to learn!

Comment: @DKru: *"webpage or reference that explains all the commands"* That's a very broad request. You should get used to using the `perldoc` command which is installed with Perl. Or you can use the [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/) web site.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is read through the file until you see the line where you want printing to begin and print up to the line where you want it to stop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ( $line =~ / Information A/ .. $line =~ / Total/ ) {
        print do { $line =~ s/^\(.\)\s+//; $line };
    }
}

__DATA__
(n) Name
(n) General info
(n) ID
(n) Contact
(n) General
(n)
(a) Information A
(a)
(a) Name
(a) one
(a) two
(a) three
(a)
(a) four
(a) five
(a) Total
(b) Information B
(b)
(b) Name
```

Since 5.14, you can use `s/...//r` instead of the `do` block there.

Also, if the file is large, you don't want to keep reading after you've seen the last line you want to print. If that's the case, you can use:

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ( $line =~ / Information A/ .. $line =~ / (Total)/ ) {
        print $line =~ s/^\(.\)\s+//r;
        last if $1 and $1 eq 'Total';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `(n)`, `(a)` and `(b)` are annotations by the author. Check the statement in their code `if (substr($line,0,13) eq 'Information A')`